# Adding client IP info into django logger

Tags: django, logging, ip

I am trying to add the client IPs to the log files, I have thought about extending the Logger, but not sure how to access the request object and put IP into the record object

```
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

class RequestRotatingFileLogger(RotatingFileHandler, object):
    def emit(self, record):
        """
        code to manipulate the record to add an attribute to have client IP
        record.ip = '123.123.123.123'
        """
        super(RequestRotatingFileLogger,self).emit(record)
```

Comment: try django_requestlogging package this one necessary for you, link https://pypi.org/project/django-requestlogging/

Comment: django-requestlogging is broken, there are seven version in github, none works with python3 and django>=2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, after reading some Logger source code, I found out a hacky way to do it

```
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

class RequestRotatingFileLogger(RotatingFileHandler, object):
        def emit(self, record):
            record.ip = '0.0.0.0'
            try:
                request = record.args[0]
                record.ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')  
                record.args = None
            except:
                pass

            super(RequestRotatingFileLogger,self).emit(record)
```

and when logging, pass the request object as second parameter eg.

```
logger.info('message', request)
```

Comment: and you define the custom class in the settings.py ?

Comment: and what format do you specify to use the ip record ?             'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(ip)s %(message)s', ?