# Is it possible to inject a variable into python logger Filter

Tags: python, logging

I want to add `session_id` to every log message. So I can do it in every request this way.

```
log.info('[%s] my message', self.session_id);
```

or even a [handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187786/adding-client-ip-info-into-django-logger). But it requires to pass `%s` and session variable to log method every time when I log something. Well, to skip the dirty job I can create a [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-filters-to-impart-contextual-information):

```
class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
  def filter(self, record):
    record.my_session = 'LOL'
    return True
```

I'm using django + tornado so I modify `LOGGING` variable in `settings.py`:

```
'filters': {
  'user_filter': {
    '()': 'my_package.ContextFilter',
   }
},

'formatters': {
'verbose': {
        'format':  '[%(asctime)s %(my_session)s] %(message)s',
    },
},
```

And when if I write something like that:

```
class A(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.session_id = random(1024)

  def process(self):
    log.info('hello')
```

I would get:

`[11:23 LOL] hello`.

Fine, now I want to inject `A.session_id` to filter instead of `LOL`. Note that `session_id` is defined in scope of `A` every time I log something. Sure I can wrap every single logger method (trace, info, debug ...) and add there session functionality but this will break line number.

I would do something like a static variable and a static setter in `ContextFilter`, but unfortunately I'm using using tornado (request are run in the same thread), which means I can't event use thread local context. Is filter the only workaround to get a custom variable for log entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17558764/3872976). I should use LoggingAdapter instead of Filter.

```
class A(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(log, {'session_id': random(1024)})

  def process(self):
    self.logger.info('hello')
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually used the Context Filter and it worked well for me. Here's a file I import (`filters.py`) which contains my Context filter:

```
import logging
from flask import request

class SessionFilter(logging.Filter):
    '''
    This class acts as a context filter for logs. If an action is executed as part of a request, this filter
    adds the session ID associated with the request to the log.
    '''

    def filter(self, record):
        try:
            record.session_id = request.headers['Cookie'].lstrip('session=')
        except:
            record.session_id = None
        return True
```